# How to go from zig zag to wave

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, patterns

Trying to replicate the image pattern below. I am currently using a long rectangle shape and adding anchor points which I can then get the zig zag in areas I want but not sure how to smoothly go from the zig zag to the wave pattern seamlessly. I've tried using 'smooth' under zig zag but then I can't move the wave positions directly over the zig zag points. Wondering if there are any tutorials or advice on achieving this same outcome. Still learning Illustrator so any advice is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make five horizontal paths separated at the same distance, the two above with a corner zig zag and a smooth zig zag. Select all and blend. Adjust the steps.

[image: blend]

The paths must be in order, the bottom one back and the others successively on the front.

[image: blend animation]

Answer (score 0):

This one was made with Adobe Illustrator.

Create the lines as shown in the image below.

Apply a **zig zag** effect in the first line.

Blend the first and the second lines.

[image]

Comment: This one was made with Adobe Illustrator... or Corel Draw, or Afinity designer, or Inkscape, etc.

Comment: I mean my answer.